# Unable to put the content of jsonp request in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, http, jsonp

I am doing a `$http.jsonp` request to a WordPress account, I am getting a status `304` which looks like this

`posts?callback=angular.callbacks._0  GET 304`,

and here is what I see in the Network part of the browser

```
Response Headers: 

Link:

</wp-json/posts?callback=angular.callbacks._0&page=2>; rel="next", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4192>; rel="item"; title="El regreso de Nicolas Jaar", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4181>; rel="item"; title="Nocturnal complet%C3%B3 su line up y va m%C3%A1s all%C3%A1 de la electr%C3%B3nica", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4164>; rel="item"; title="24 Horas Non-Stop con Marco Carola", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4113>; rel="item"; title="Richie Hawtin recibe doctorado de honor en Universidad Britanica", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4106>; rel="item"; title="%E2%80%9CMi casa es su casa%E2%80%9D el festival del house en San Jos%C3%A9", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4096>; rel="item"; title="Urbanet Radio lanza su primer Showcase en el Hoxton Pub", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4091>; rel="item"; title="Frankfurt, sede del Museo de M%C3%BAsica Electr%C3%B3nica Moderna", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4084>; rel="item"; title="Caricaco y la m%C3%BAsica costarricense vibraron en Guanacaste", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4037>; rel="item"; title="Un vistazo al Abbey Road Studios", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4075>; rel="item"; title="Mira el trailer de la pelicula "El principito"", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4072>; rel="item"; title="Mira el primer episodio de la caricatura de Major Lazer", <http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/4052>; rel="item"; title="El arte del blunt para celebrar el 420"
```

so that is the exact Object I need, see the request here in the service and the controller

```
.service('FreshlyPressed', function($http, $q) {
  return {

    getBlogs: function($scope) {
      var posts = [];
      $http.jsonp('http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .success(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
          $scope.posts = result;
        })
    }
});

.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, FreshlyPressed) {

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $scope.posts = FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  };
  $scope.doRefresh();
});
```

and the html

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <a ng-href="#/tabs/news/{{post.ID}}">
    <h2 ng-bind-html="post.title"></h2>
    <p>{{:: post.date | date}}</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

and I am doing it this way with the jsonp because of `Access-Allow-Control-Origin`.

[Here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KlfmqW2eLDdEhf90Dsuy?p=preview) just in case you want to take a look.

The problem is that if you use a simple `$http.get` you are able to see the posts rendered in the view but only in your local environment in the browser, but once you try to run the app in the mobile, then this error comes up

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

adding the `$http.jsonp` makes the request clear, the error isn't there anymore, but you can't see the data in the DOM.

**EDIT**

now, according to my issue, I just see in the Changelog view of the plugin, a text

`Add handling for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) OPTIONS requests.
Preflighted requests (using the OPTIONS method) include the headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials in the response, if the HTTP origin is set.`

just in case, [this is the plugin I am using, WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/changelog/)

what does it mean ?

Comment: Site not serving jsonp, and is not CORS enabled. Will have to use a proxy to get the data

Comment: @charlietfl I am using Firebase as a backend, can Firebase do something here ?

Comment: I doubt it, it would have to act like a server and make a request to other site and return the data . Could use YQL to get it though. It's basically a free proxy

Comment: Where is the root of this problem ? beside using a proxy, is there something I can do in the Angular part ? or in the request. What are the options I have ?

Comment: None... it's due to `same origin policy`

Comment: @charlietfl ok, so no jsonp. Only proxy ? I had a bad time retrieving the posts from the WP, now I have those posts, once I achieved what I want, now I have a bigger problem here. Can't believe it.

Comment: Not hard to use YQL. They have a sandbox console, can get your url sorted out in just a few minutes. Response format is a bit different but well documented and easy to see in sandbox

Comment: Ok, and doing that will work in any other device or browser ? @charlietfl

Comment: It's Yahoo..if there's an internet connection will work

Comment: hey, @charlietfl in the docs for the plugin I am using says ```Add handling for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) OPTIONS requests.

Preflighted requests (using the OPTIONS method) include the headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials in the response, if the HTTP origin is set.``` what does it mean ?

Comment: @charlietfl https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/changelog/ or see my question EDIT part.

Comment: that's for output from that particular server/wordprss installation and allows enabling CORS

Comment: @charlietfl so that will not fix my issue. I will be reading YQL tonight. Thanks